# How to dump output from external command into editor?

Tags: external-command

In example, I would like to paste the current time or date into editor by using external commands (such as `date`) without leaving vim.

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply run

```
:%!date
```

(or whatever command you wish to dump into the current buffer).

This will replace the entire buffer with the command's output. If you don't want this, use `read` instead:

```
:read !date
```

Or, you can replace a certain line with the output of an external command:

```
:2!date  replace line 2 with the current date
:$!date  replace the last line with the current date
:.!date  replace the current line with the current date
```

This also works with `read`, but appends after that line instead (ex. use `:$read !date` to append the current date to the file).

Comment: the reason I wanted to dump to editor was so I could search the output better. Is there not a way like `cmd > vim` or something?

Answer (score 5):

A more complex example, to run a Python script on the current buffer, putting the output in a new tab:

```
:tabnew | r ! python -c "import json, sys; json.load(sys.stdin)" < #
```

- `tabnew` opens a new tab
- `r` is short for `read`
- `!` executes a shell command
- `python -c` executes an inline python script
- `json.load(sys.stdin)` tries to load (parse) json from stdin
- `< #` redirects the *previous* buffer (the current one pre `tabnew`) into the command

Comment: note that `json.tool` works as well for this particular purpose, but I wanted to show something simple for redirection of `#` with an inline script.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Nice answer demonstrating `#`—maybe mention `%` too? +1 from me, anyways.

Answer (score 2):

In addition Doorknob answer, it's also possible to use the shortcut for `read` as `r!`, in example:

```
:r!date
```

Some other useful example would include doing some math like calculating number of bytes in gigabyte:

```
:r! echo $((1024**3))
:r! echo $((1024*1024*1024))
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that `bc` can be good for quick math, i.e., `:r! bc -l << '2^30'`.

Comment: @HAL9001 I know this is dated, but for that kind of think I would just use `<C-r>=`

Answer (score 1):

A plugin I've been using to do this is [clam.vim](https://github.com/sjl/clam.vim).

After installing it, you can do

```
:Clam date
```

to put the date in a new buffer. You can run pretty arbitrarily complex commands, so

```
:Clam find . -iname '*.vim'
```

or

```
:Clam ./my-script
```

is also possible.