# How can I import output from linux commands into vim for editing?

Tags: external-command

1. Is there a way I can directly import/insert the output of any linux command into vim editor? For example: `pwd` in currently open vim buffer.

Also

2. From terminal how can I directly open command output for manipulation? For example: opening `lshw` output in vim and filter unwanted info and quick save file.

Comment: related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/795/5298

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Import shell output

Launch vi or vim and try:

```
!!pwd
```

The output will be pasted in the current buffer

Checkout the possible options:

```
:help !!
```

#### Pipe `stdout` to vim

Try:

```
pwd | vi -
```

Comment: `!!pwd` in vim execution mode doesnt seems to work for me. However, as @statox suggested `:read !pwd` works perfectly. And thankyou for pipe stdout to vim - exactly what I needed :D

Comment: @AviMehenwal to clarify this answer: `!!` should be use in normal mode (not in command line mode). This will open the command line with `:.!` and you can then type your command to get `:.!pwd` which means insert the result of the external command `!pwd` at the current line `.` you can also use `:$!pwd` to put the result on the last line, `:1!ls -l` to put the result on the first line or use whatever line number you want.

Comment: Amazing ... hacky way to get things done :) Thanks for explanation and it works like you suggested.

Comment: @statox `:.!pwd` does _not_ mean "insert the result of the external command at the current line".  It means "write the current line as the input to the external command and _replace_ this line with the output".  The current line is being filtered through the external command.  To simply insert the output of a command after a certain line, the desired address should be used as the range for `:[range]read !cmd`.

Comment: `pwd | vim -` worked great

Answer (score 10):

You could use `:read` (see [`:h :read`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#%3aread)):

> ```
> :[range]r[ead] [++opt] !{cmd}
>           Execute {cmd} and insert its standard output below
>           the cursor or the specified line.  A temporary file is
> ```

For example: `:read ! pwd` will put the current working directory at the cursor position.

Note that you can pipe your command to grep to filter what you want.